# change --name in Windows ./synergy.exe call

Tags: synergy

I've changed the name of my Win7 machine since installing synergy yet the command being run in the background still does --name oldName.  I've tried removing and reinstalling synergy with no luck.  Would anyone happen to know where its getting that command from?  The output in the log is

> Running synergy: ./synergys.exe -f --debug NOTE --name 195L -c
>   C:/Users/myUserName/AppData/Local/Temp/qt_temp.uD1824 --address :24800
>
> unknown screen name `195L'

I thought of just changing it back, but the synergy UI won't allow me to create a screen with  a leading digit, so I can't go back to 195L.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy adds registry entries.  Try looking in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synergy`.  I'm using W2K3, and I have the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synergy\Synergy\server`, although it's blank for me; it may have the value you're looking for, though.